# Ajax load content into div from a json array

Tags: php, javascript, json, jquery

My webpage is supposed to generating a series of questions in a random order. Each question is a seperate HTML page with a picture and multiple options.On page load, there should a default question and thereafter on clicking next a new page is loaded. I am currently:

1. Creating a php array with the names of the html pages and shuffling it.
2. Converting this array into a json array to be accessed in Javascript.
3. Trying to ajax load the page.

I am stuck at the third step; how do you send a json array element in an ajax call i.e.

```
$.ajax({
  url: name+".html",
  success: function(html){
    $("#container").empty().append(html);
  }
});
```

where name is the name of the webpage stored in the json array and container is the div on my current php page.
In case there is an easier way of doing the above task, I am open to that too.

Thanks!

EDIT
Step 2:

```
         var xdata = <?php echo json_encode($testArray); ?>;
```

where $testArray is the php shuffled array of webpages.

Comment: So name.html is expecting the json array?  You're sending it as a cgi variable?

Comment: Name is expecting an element of the json array. For example Test1. Basically I want the ajax call to retrieve Test1.html and display it in the container.

Comment: How will you get the JSON to begin with?

Comment: can you post how you are doing point 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [jQuery load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

```
var pageToLoadIntoContainer = 'Test1.html';

$('#container').load( pageToLoadIntoContainer );
```

Extending this answer to try and solve all of your elements...

```
<?php

$pageArray = shuffle(array(
  'Test1' ,
  'Test2' ,
  'Test3'
));

....

?>
<script>

var pageArray = <?php echo json_encode( $pageArray ); ?>;

....

$('#container1').load( pageArray[0] );
$('#container2').load( pageArray[1] );
$('#container3').load( pageArray[2] );

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this is what I was looking for and it should work!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({ url: name+".html", success: function(html)     
                $("#container").empty().append(html);                           
                }                                      
                });
```

there are 1 '{'   and  2 '}'
try

```
$.ajax({ url: name+".html", success: function(html){     
                $("#container").empty().append(html);                           
                }                                      
                });
```